# How to read node values in xml by giving node id

Tags: c#, .net, xml

```
<GlobalNavigation>
<primarylink>
<secondarylink>
    <linkid>1</linkid>
    <linkName>3</linkname>
    <secondary>
        <leftnav>
            <linkid>left1</linkid>
            <linkName>linktext</linkname>
        </leftnav>
    </secondary>
</secondarylink>
</GlobalNavigation>
```

i want to read leftnav linkname by giving linkid.

Comment: Try to be more clear what you want to do.

Comment: <GlobalNavigation>
<primarylink>
<secondarylink>
 <linkid>1</linkid>
 <linkName>3</linkname>
 <secondary>
  <leftnav>
   <linkid>left1</linkid>
   <linkName>linktext</linkname>
  </leftnav>
 </secondary>
</secondarylink>
</GlobalNavigation>

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The simplest way is to use LINQ to XML:

```
var doc = XDocument.Load(...);

string linkId = "left1";
var linkName = doc.Descendants("leftnav")
                  .Elements("linkid")
                  .Where(x => x.Value == linkId)
                  .Single()
                  .Parent.Element("linkName").Value;
```

In other words:

- Look in each `leftnav` element
- Look in each `linkid` element directly under it
- Find a `linkid` element with the desired value
- There should be exactly one of these (there are other options you may wish to use here, which would change the rest of the solution). Select this one `linkid` element.
- Take the parent element
- Find the first `linkName` element under it
- Extract the value (i.e. the text within it)

Comment: There are so many places to fail with exception on using the dot after a nullable: Single()., Parent., Element(). You should use SelectMany + SingleOrDefault

Comment: @George: It depends how you want to handle the failure. If an exception being thrown is appropriate, it's the simplest way of expressing the requirements. That's why I mentioned other options in the "there should be exactly one of these" bit.

Comment: Agree, but i would not rely on a bunch of diverse exceptions just to report a query miss, when it can easily be avoided. Also, can't see how an NullReferenceException or an InvalidOperationException can be appropriate in this case.

Comment: @George: If you're not expecting to *catch* the exception, it's probably as good as any other - it'll be reasonably clear which step has failed from the stack trace. You say it can *easily* be avoided - I suspect that avoiding it *while giving good diagnostics of which step failed* would make the query rather more complicated. Just getting a null reference instead is easy, but in many cases that's not appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

You can search it with xpath.
This solution is vulnerable to injection because of string concatenation in xpath.

```
XElement source = ...

var linkId = "left1";

var linkName =
    source.XPathSelectElements(@"leftnav[linkid='" + linkId + @"']/linkName")
        .Select(i=>i.Value).SingleOrDefault();
```

I recommend to use the following:

```
var linkId = "left1";
var query =
 from leftNavElement in source.Descendants("leftnav")
 from linkIdElement in leftNavElement.Elements("linkid")
 where linkIdElement.Value == linkId
 from linkNameElement in leftNavElement.Elements("linkName")
 select linkNameElement.Value;

var linkName = query.SingleOrDefault();
```

It uses linq and handles the cases where no matching element is found.

The value of linkName will be null if there is no match in both solutions.

Comment: fixed the code, initial was not take 'leftnav' tag name into account

Answer (score 1):

An even easier way is to use XPathing. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256086%28VS.85%29.aspx

Good thing about xpathing is that it will work in .net 2.0 AND you can get what you want in one line!...

```
xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("secondaryLink/secondary/link[/linkid="123"]/linkname")
```